# AngularJS shared REST service between modules and controllers

Tags: angularjs, rest

I need to have a set of resource factories to consume a rest api and use that in all of my modules and controllers. I'm confused as to how this should be separated and how to access the factories from controller.

As an example, let's assume I have:

```
// rest.js
angular.module('myApp.rest', ['ngResource'] )
    .factory('Book', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/book', {}, {
            getBook: {
                method: 'GET'
            },
        });
    })
```

Here's the main module as `myApp`:

```
 // app.js
 angular.module('myApp', [

        'ngRoute',
        'ngResource',

        'app.rest',
        'app.library'

    ])
      .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/book', {
                    templateUrl: 'someTemplate',
                    controller: 'LibraryCTRL',
                });
```

Now I want to have another module called `app.library` which can use `Book` resource. How the Dependency Injection would look like?

More important question: Is this the right way to do it? I mean is it better to attach the whole `Book` factory to `myApp` or use a separate `myApp.rest` module?

```
// library.js
angular
    .module('myApp.library', ['ngResource']) // INJECT REST MODULE HERE?
    .controller('LibraryCtrl', Library);

// INJECT BOOK RESOURCE HERE? 
Library.$inject = [];

// USE BOOK IN THIS CONSTRUCTOR
function Library() {

    var vm = this;

    // USING IT
    Book.getBook(function(data){
         vm.book = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's Abstract the problem

as i understand you want to make custom factory "service" which can be used in all modules and controllers that is responsible for consuming rest api

so you will have `serviceModule.js`

```
var ServiceApp = angular.module('ServiceApp', []);
ServiceApp
        .factory(
                'restControllerService',
                [
                        '$http',
                        function($http) {

                            var doRequest = 
                            function(URL) {
                                    return $http({
                                        method : 'get',
                                        url :  URL, 
                                       headers : {
                                       'Content-Type' :'application/json'
                                                 }
                                    });
                                    });
                                }

                            }
                            return {
                                getBook : function() {
                                    return doRequest('api/book');
                                }
                            };
                        } ]);
```

you can inject that in any other module like that

```
var library = angular.module('libraryModule', [ "ServiceApp" ]);
libraryModule.controller('LibraryCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        'restControllerService',
        function($scope,restControllerService) {

            $scope.book = null;

            $scope.getbook = function() {

                    restControllerService.getbook('api/book').success(
                            function(data) {
                                $scope.book = data;
                            }).error(function() {
                        $scope.book = null;
                    });
                }
            };
```

Comment: Thanks. Here you're creating `restControllerService` as part of the main module 'ServiceApp`. If I have the `restControllerService` in another module called, `ServiceApp.rest`, then how the injection would change?

Comment: sorry what do you mean "If I have the `restControllerService` in another module" you mean calling that service or define an new service with the same name

Comment: You have a module called `ServiceApp` and defined the `restControllerService` on that module. But I have two separate modules. One has the service one doesn't.

Comment: inject ServiceApp as a dependency in the other module and inject  the restControllerService service in the controller level and use the service as presented in second code snippet above

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to do this:
myApp --> myApp.library --> myApp.rest

You're pretty much there. Just make myApp.library inject the myApp.rest module.

```
angular
    .module('myApp.library', ['myApp.rest'])
    .controller('LibraryCtrl', ['Book', function(Book) {
     // use Book.getBook() here.
    }]);
```

Also remove the dependency of myApp.rest and ngResource from myApp module, since you're not using them there.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'app.library'
    ])
```

In general, only add a dependency if you're directly using it in that module.

I don't believe there is a best practice for how to separate code into modules. Personally, I like to have a single module for an entire application, unless I'm trying to reuse a piece of code in another application.

Comment: The injection must be at the module level or controller level? In your example, how can I use `Book` resource in `LibraryCtrl`?

Comment: Yes, inject Book at the controller level. In general, you need to inject modules at the module level, and services at controller level.